# Errno 13 Permission denied error when trying to load Huggingface dataset

Tags: python, macos, permissions, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to do a very simple thing: to load a dataset from the Huggingface library (see example code [here](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/2?fw=pt)) on my Mac:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "mrpc")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads/6d9bc094a0588d875caee4e51df39ab5d6b6316bf60695294827b02601d421a5.759f3e257a3fad0984d9f8ba9a26479d341795eb50fa64e4c1de40f1fc421313.py.lock'
```

I've just spent an hour googling solutions for this, but so far nothing has worked. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Have you tried to change the permissions of the directory using `chmod 777 /Users/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried that just now but got the following error: "chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads: Operation not permitted". I guess there's a bigger permissions issue here?

Comment: Hello again! In order to change the permissions of that folder, please contact the owner. If not, simply move your codes and data (also outputs) to a folder created by you. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am the owner of the folder, that's why I'm surprised the 'chmod 777' command didn't work. But thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve it by manually changing the permissions of the right folders on my Mac:

1. I navigated to the /Users/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads folder in the Finder (you can see hidden files and folders such as ".cache" by pressing " command shift + . ")
2. Then I went to the info window for this 'downloads' folder (" command i "), clicked 'Sharing & Permissions', clicked the lock to make changes and then gave everyone read & write access (I'm the only one using this computer, so it doesn't matter)
3. I then got some new permission errors relating to some other folders, so I just went to each folder and changed the permissions for all of them

Not sure why this worked and the 'chmod 777' command didn't, but I'm glad it did. Thank you @Cuartero for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Another solution is to use the 'cache_dir' flag to change the directory where the data are saved, e.g.:

raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "cola",cache_dir="/Users/username/Desktop")

Comment: According to Huggingface you can also set the 'HF_HOME' variable to a certain directory that will then be the default directory where everything is saved, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

cmd shift .
delete .cache file
cd ~/stable-diffusion-webui;./webui.sh